# IONIC : click event taking time for selecting places from Google Places api

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, onclick, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I am new to IONIC. I am trying to use google places api in my ionic app. I am able to get the places via Google Places api. But the problem is I have to long press the autocomplete option in the app or else the selection is not reflected in the app.

Here is my Html code.

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&amp;libraries=places"></script>    
<input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box" data-tap-disabled="true">
<div id="map" data-tap-disabled="true"></div>
```

And this is my MapController.js

```
     .controller('MapCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, $state, $cordovaGeolocation, $ionicLoading, Markers, $ionicPopup, $location, SearchAll, shareData, constants) {        
initAutocomplete();

        function initAutocomplete() {
          console.log("in Map Autocomplete");
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                center: { lat: 19.075984, lng: 72.877656 },
                zoom: 13,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            });

            // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
            var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
            var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
            // map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

            // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
            map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
                searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
            });

            var markers = [];
            // [START region_getplaces]
            // Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
            // more details for that place.
            searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
                var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

                console.log("in searchBox Listner");

                if (places.length == 0) {
                    return;
                }

                console.log("Places : ", places);
                console.log("LAT : ", places[0].geometry.location.lat());
                console.log("LAONG : ", places[0].geometry.location.lng());
                // Clear out the old markers.
                markers.forEach(function(marker) {
                    marker.setMap(null);
                });
                markers = [];

                // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
                var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
                places.forEach(function(place) {
                    var icon = {
                        url: place.icon,
                        size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
                        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                        anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
                        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
                    };

                    // Create a marker for each place.
                    markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
                        map: map,
                        icon: icon,
                        title: place.name,
                        position: place.geometry.location
                    }));

                    if (place.geometry.viewport) {
                        // Only geocodes have viewport.
                        bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
                    } else {
                        bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
                    }
                });
                map.fitBounds(bounds);
            });
            // [END region_getplaces]
        }
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution for this problem is discussed at https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/1798. The issue is that google dynamically adds elements that need the data-tap-disabled property, so you'll have to manually add the property after google has added these elements to the dom.

```
$scope.disableTap = function () {
    var container = document.getElementsByClassName('pac-container');
    angular.element(container).attr('data-tap-disabled', 'true');
    var backdrop = document.getElementsByClassName('backdrop');
    angular.element(backdrop).attr('data-tap-disabled', 'true');
    // leave input field if google-address-entry is selected
    angular.element(container).on("click", function () {
        document.getElementById('pac-input').blur();
    });
};
```

now add `ng-change='disableTap()'` to your `input`:

```
<input ng-change='disableTap()' id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box" data-tap-disabled="true">
```

The github link uses `ng-focus` but `ng-change` worked better for me because sometimes the generated elements didn't exist yet by the time focus was fired.

Comment: Thank you for a quick reply . It worked . 

To make it working I replaced 
    inputEl.blur(); 
WITH
    document.getElementById('pac-input').blur();


and In the Html Added ng-model in the in input type as we are using ng-change ..

Thank You Were Much . It saved a lot of time